# How can I allow editing the value in the combolist of C1FlexGrid in vb10?

Tags: vb.net, componentone, c1flexgrid

How to allow editing the value in the combolist of C1FlexGrid in vb10?
Is it not okay to type the value in the combolist of `c1` flex grid?

I am using the following snippet

```
GridComboTransferStr = dbRow("RSPrice1") & "|" & Trim(GridComboTransferStr) & ""
```

Comment: It is okay for me to type the data in the combolist property.The code is....."  GridComboTransferStr = "|" & dbRow("RSPrice1") & "|" & Trim(GridComboTransferStr) & "" i got the solution from "http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.4~C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.C1FlexGridBase~ComboList.html"

Answer (score 4):

ComboList in C1FlexGrid in a ComponentOne Studio for Winforms works analogous to ComboList in DatGridView of MS Controls. ComboList can be editable in C1FlexGrig in VB10. *In fact it is an important and widely used functionality of C1FlexGrid.*

The **ComboList** property of C1FlexGrid enables this functionality. It specifies the type of editor to be used when editing a cell. You may use a **text box**, **drop-down list**, **drop-down combo**, or an **edit button** to pop up custom editor forms.

To use the ComboList property, set the **AllowEditing** property to **true** and respond to the **BeforeEdit** event by setting the **ComboList** property to a **string** that describes the type of editing you want to use for that cell. The options are described below:

- To edit the cell using a regular **text box**, set the ComboList property to an empty string. For example:

  flex.ComboList = string.Empty
- To edit the cell using a **drop-down list**, set the ComboList property to a string containing the available options, separated by pipe characters. For example:

  flex.ComboList = "Item 1|Item 2|Item 3"
- To edit the cell using a **drop-down combo**, set the ComboList property to a string containing the available options, separated by pipe characters ("|") and starting with a pipe character. For example:

  flex.ComboList = "|Item 1|Item 2|Item 3"
- To display an **edit button**, set the ComboList property to a string containing an ellipsis ("..."). Edit buttons look like regular push buttons, aligned to the right of the cell, with an ellipsis as a caption. When the user clicks on the edit button, the grid fires the CellButtonClick event. In this case, the user can't edit the cell contents directly. For example:

  flex.ComboList = "..."
- To display an **edit button next to an editable cell**, set the ComboList property to a string containing a pipe and an ellipsis ("|..."). In this case, you get a regular edit button but the user can also edit the cell contents directly. For example:

  flex.ComboList = "|..."

**Example**:

The code below handles the BeforeEdit event and assigns a value to the ComboList property so that the grid displays buttons on every other row.

```
Private Sub _flex_BeforeEdit(sender As Object, e As RowColEventArgs)
    _flex.ComboList = String.Empty
    If e.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
        _flex.ComboList = "..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer, using the pipe in `"|..."` was the solution !